# For what operators are $sin(ax)$ and $cos(bx)$ eigenfunctions?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

So it is clear that the operator $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ is an eigenfunction of $sin(ax)$ and $cos(ax)$. For what other operators are sins and cosines eigenfunctions?

Comment: Other way around. Any polynomial in $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ will also work.

Comment: $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}$, $\frac{d^6}{dx^6}+3\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, etc, etc.

Comment: Okay, but anything that isn't so obvious?